# access centeral xampp phpmyadmin database on localserver

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, mysql-workbench

i have installed xampp on the local server pc.

I am trying to access the database through mysqlworkbench from 1 pc to other PC(Server).

but it is giving the below error

```
Connecting to MySQL server 192.168.0.102...

Host 'KILL3RCODER-LAP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I tried to search web for it and did the changes to `httpd-xampp.conf` file.
Here below is my conf file and still i am getting the same problem :(

```
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
    UnsetEnv PERL5LIB
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadModule php5_module modules/php5apache2_2.dll

<IfModule php5_module>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>

    PHPINIDir "/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
<IfModule !php5_module>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
    <IfModule actions_module>
        Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>


<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "/xampp/php/"
<Directory "/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php5_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /security "/xampp/security/htdocs/"
    <Directory "/xampp/security/htdocs">
        <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "xamppsecurity.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
   </Directory>

    Alias /licenses "/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
    <LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|phpmyadmin|licenses|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    #Deny from all
    Allow from all
    #Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
    #fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
    #fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16
    Require all granted

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

I am still not authorized after editing the above file..
I want to have centeral db for my local network..
What to do?

Comment: does 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' work?

Comment: @RenePot
Yes localhost command works on that server.
it is xampp page is opening fine on server.
also the phpmyadmin is opening through `localhost/phpmyadmin`
but it requires username and pass which i have to type the username as root

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows to specify access rights per user **and** per host. And by default there's certainly no user that is allowed to connect from your specific IP address. Probably the the anyhost access for root is also disabled, so what you have to do is to grant access for the specific user plus its host address from where it connects (or anyhost: %).

You can do this by running Workbench on the server machine where you can log in. Go to the admin section and either create a new user with % as host part or add a root user with % access. Specify the actual machine address if you want to restrict access to this machine only.